# Localscroll toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

For many sites (including mine) it would really be useful if we could use jQuery localscroll to send someone to the end of the site, and then when they reach the end, reverse the direction, so the next click would take you back up to the top of the site.

Has anyone done something like this? Any ideas on how to accomplish it (I'm a js newbie).

Answer (score 0):

Well this code may do what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vngh4/1/)

```
var bottom = false;
$('body').delegate('span', 'click', function() {
if (bottom === true) {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: '0px'
    }, "slow");
    bottom = false;
} else {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, "slow");
    bottom = true;
}
});
```

Comment: Hmm... it's not working for me or maybe I'm just too dense to figure it out. I should have mentioned that I'm using localscroll with a fixed element so that the page scrolls underneath it. My thought was that visitors could click it to dive down to the bottom of the long page and click again to go back up to the top.           $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#thefloatingnav').localScroll(600);

   })